# No tag for Amazon Machine Learning

Tags: feature-request, tags

I wanted to ask one question related to Amazon Machine Learning but when I tagged the question I found that there is no tag for it.

How to create a tag for this?

This is the question:

- [Solution to fabricate data using current dataset for training: amazon machine learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068939/solution-to-fabricate-data-using-current-dataset-for-training-amazon-machine-le)

Comment: When you reach 1500 rep you can create new tags when asking/editing questions

Comment: I'm sure someone will be happy to create the tag for you if there's consensus it's a useful tag to have around. Can you post an example question that would go into that tag?

Comment: @Pekka웃 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30068939/solution-to-fabricate-data-using-current-dataset-for-training-amazon-machine-learning

Comment: I'm not familiar with the field but I'm not 100% sure whether it's a good on-topic question for SO. Could anyone with experience weigh in?

Comment: Not familiar with the domain either, but I agree with @Pekka웃. I would be tempted to give it an "unclear what you're asking". I can't picture how somebody else can create data for you. Particularly if you give no indication what kind of data we're talking about.

Comment: as you very correctly said , you have no idea of domain :) @RetoKoradi

Comment: Looks like your asking for magic to happen. Do you have any theoretical basis for knowing that what you're asking for is in fact doable? (If it was possible to widen a learning dataset procedurally, I wonder why people would even bother gathering large training sets at all these days.)

Comment: ok , what i am asking is in lieu with the idea of machine learning. Machine/Model sees and analyzes the data patterns & predict the output by using training data. If that is possible then it can be possible that   aws, which is managed service may have some provision for generating data by itself. but again what i asked for was is there any way to do that. It could have been a simple yes and explanation or no and explanation. What is the point in saying question is unclear of what it is refferring to ? also why people want training data sets of their own because that is more reliable . @Mat

Comment: see what i think the OP is asking in his question is quite clear, may be try to see the question in other perspective. As ML forms a part of AI it may be possible. @RetoKoradi , mat ,pekka

Comment: Could definitely benefit from some editing, but it seems like there's a reasonably clear and answerable question in there. @Mat Knowing that something is possible to do isn't a criteria for asking about it on SO; worst case the answers just explain that it's not possible because of X, Y or Z. There are plenty of JavaScript questions asking how to do things that can't actually be done due to browser security restrictions.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: If I thought that alone was a reason to close, I'd have voted to close.

Comment: besides, my initial question was "No tag for Amazon MAchine learning". As  aws guys have launched a new service there must be some tag for it at SO. if the question bashing is over can we concentrate on that ? @Mat